# Can't extrude edges with individual origins

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, extrude

I'm trying to extrude my edges along a road to create things like gutters, or sidewalks etc. I've tried many different extrude options and none of them seem to extrude each edge in the correct direction, they seem to follow where the origin is or something. Here's a gif that better explains what's going on:

[image: modelin]

I'm using the industry compatible hotkeys on blender 2.82, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the Edge Slide tool is better suited for this.

1. Select the edge and use the *Edge Slide* tool
2. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to disable Clamp and slide it outwards
3. Done.

*(The yellow guides appear when you press C (disable clamp))*
[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks! Unclamping was the secret sauce :)